# Latex how to change section numbering

Tags: numbering

I am using Latex to write my thesis and I wanted to change the section and subsection numbering from 1.0.1, and 1.0.2 to 1.1 and 1.2 respectively.

I am using report class to write my thesis but have not been able to find any resources to override the numbering.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear.  Does you document has chapters? If yes, It seems that in (some) `chapter` you have only `subsection`s and not `sections`.  If this is the case in the whole document, than simply replace `subsection`s with `section`. Please advice.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. I was not using the sections feature and was simply using subsections for each chapter. Thanks so much for clearing this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try to put one of the following lines in front of the line `\begin{document}` (i.e. in the preamble)

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

This will change the format of the numbering of section and chapter.

Comment: But then if OP uses a subsection or section (respectively), references will break in strange ways.  It would be much better to follow the comment not skip the sectioning level.